# Reflect changes from BindingList.List.Element between controls and the Bindinglist

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a `BindingList` of `objectA`s bound to `comboBox_1.DataSource` (and object's name as `DisplayMember`). My `objectA` consists of `objectZ` and a list of `objectX`s. The form is connected to one specific element from that `objectX`s list. There are many other controls on this form which show values of different properties of `objectX`.
Here's some code to visualize that:

```
class objectA
{
    class objectZ
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
    class objectX
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public objectZ Z { get; set; }
    public List<objectX> listX { get; set; }
}

BindingList<objectA> listA = new BindingList<objectA>();
comboBox_1.DataSource = listA;
comboBox_1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

How do I make it so `objectX` values in other controls change to reflect currently chosen value in `comboBox` while retaining the `BindingList` property of reading/writing data 'on-the-go'? To express it in code (aka What I'm trying to achieve):

```
textBox_1.Text = listA.GetWantedObjectX().Prop1;
checkBox_1.Checked = listA.GetWantedObjectX().Prop2;

void checkBox_1_CheckedChanged()
{
    listA.GetWantedObjectX().Prop2 = checkBox_1.Checked;
}
```

I'm guessing I'd need a `objectA.objectX currentObject` property to control the data and then it'd be:

```
currentObject = listA.GetWantedObjectX();
checkBox_1.Checked = currentObject.Prop2;
```

But then changes made to `currentObject` would not be reflected in `listaA` and I'd have to create sth like a save button, right? Is there a more 'responsive' way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not a pretty solution (noone provided a better one), I basically sticked with that `currentObject` and controlling everything inside a `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Here's the code for that:

```
objectA.objectX currentObject = null;
int previousObjectIndex = 0;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentObject == null)
    {
        currentObject = listA[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].GetWantedObjectX();
        textBox1.Text = currentObject.Prop1;
    }
    else
    {
        currentObject.Prop1 = textBox1.Text;

        if (!listA[previousObjectIndex].listX.Any(x => x.Prop1 == currentObject.Prop1))
            listA[previousObjectIndex].listX.Add(currentObject);

        currentObject = listA[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].GetWantedObjectX();

        if (currentObject == null)
            currentObject = new objectA.objectX();

        previousObjectIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

        textBox1.Text = currentObject.Prop1;
    }
}
```

Of course this does not include handling of `objectZ`, where a similiar mechanic would need to be introduced.